# Onesignal promptPermission() is not applicable in Android

Tags: flutter, notifications, onesignal

i'm using [onesignal_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/onesignal_flutter) to push notifications to my app, but im facing this error, i did everything in the docs, still facing the same problem, any solution ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case on `Android` I remove this line `await OneSignal.shared.promptUserForPushNotificationPermission();`